# Failed Steam installs on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, steam

I keep trying to install steam but only get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 17.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                       libtxc-dxtn0:i386 but it is not installable
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgpg-error0:i386 (>= 1.10) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxcb-dri3-0:i386 (>= 1.11.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxinerama1:i386 (>= 2:1.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.8) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libxss1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                       
E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 9h 59min 37s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 10h 0min 37s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 9h 58min 57s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

`sudo apt upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Apparently I need libc6:amd64 libc6:i386 libegl1:amd64 libegl1:i386 libgbm1:amd64 libgbm1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1:amd64 libgl1:i386 steam-libs-amd64:amd64 steam-libs-i386:i386 How do you install these?

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: It looks like you added a repo for steam. You didn't need that so you can remove it. Then run `sudo apt update` again followed by `sudo apt install steam` - Also, please review edit history for examples of code fences (you need to use backticks instead of apostrophes, and the three backticks need to be on a new line before and after the code block)

Comment: Beginning with 20.04 many of the 32 bit libraries got removed and only a select set is kept , and you need to enable those libraries by adding the architecture via `dpkg` have a look at the question i linked this question to. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` should be the thing you're looking for.

Comment: Nmath, After doing```sudo apt install steam``` I get this: ```reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
steam:i386 is already the newest version (1:1.0.0.74).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded```

Comment: Remove everything you have done and install it from the vendor's page https://store.steampowered.com/about/  The package that gets installed is called `steam-launcher` along with its dependencies. It will also install the proper ppa.